# Paste Pose Flipped is working incorrectly and I can't figure out why

Tags: animation, rigging, armature, bones

I am having some trouble with flipping a walking pose, when I paste in the pose using the paste pose flipped button all it does is spin the model around 180 degrees so it's facing backwards, it doesn't actually flip or mirror anything. I'm just left with a model pointing backwards and if I spin it around to face the correct direction it's in the exact same position as before. Anyone know what might be going on?

Comment: hello, maybe you need to correct one of your bones orientation in Edit mode? Please share your armature: https://pasteall.org/blend/

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: @moonboots I pasted the model to the link

Comment: you need to share the link it will give you

Comment: right, sorry, never used this thing before. Here is is. https://pasteall.org/blend/0ee810765eaa46d1971dcec7e9f2b98a